# WampServer->Mysql can't get data (Always return NULL)

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I had successfully launched Apache, but after I write a simple login.html and login.php I find that I get the data in Mysql database.

There is no runtime error but the object I get using `$result=$conn->query($sql);` is always NULL;

**OS: Windows 8.1** [Wampserver latest version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/Wampserver%202.5/wampserver2.5-Apache-2.4.9-Mysql-5.6.17-php5.5.12-64b.exe/download)

login.php

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '' , 'mylogin');
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM logintable";
  $result=$conn->query($sql);

  echo "\n".var_dump($result)."\n";
  //The problem is the query can't any data, so I delete the following code.
?>
```

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
     <script language="javascript"type="text/javascript" >
         function check(){
             var name=LoginForm.username.value;
             var pwd=LoginForm.password.value;
             if(name==""){
                  alert("Enter Username");
                  LoginForm.username.focus();
                  return (false);
             }
             if(pwd==""){
                  alert("Enter Password");
                  LoginForm.password.focus();
                  return (false);
             }
         }
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div class="center">
         <form name="LoginForm" method="post" action="login.php" onsubmit="return check(this)">
             username:<input name="username" type="text"id="username"/><br />
             password:<input name="password" type="password"id="password"/><br/>
             <input value="Login" type="submit" name="submit"/>
             <input value="register" type="button"onclick="javascrtpt:window.location.href='register.html'"/>
             <br/>
         </form>
     </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**What the echo always print:**

```
object(mysqli_result)[2]
  public 'current_field' => null
  public 'field_count' => null
  public 'lengths' => null
  public 'num_rows' => null
  public 'type' => null
```

Comment: I guess its time to read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). But basically when you issue a `$result=$conn->query($sql);` you are running a query on the database. Once that completes without errors you then need to `fetch` the data that is selected by the query using something like `$obj = $result->fetch_object()`

Answer (score 0):

Now I can get data using this way:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '' , 'mylogin');
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM logintable";

  if($result=$conn->query($sql))
  {
      echo "\n".var_dump($result)."\n";

      $row = $result->fetch_row();
      echo "\n".var_dump($row)."\n";
  } 
?>
```

**What the `$result` is?**